# How to limit number of Core utilization by GluonCV

Tags: python, mxnet

I am trying same GluonCV inferencing examples. However I want to benchmark the results on a single core.
I tried to play with ctx gave cpu(0) but still unable to limit the number of cores which are getting utilized.

I Tried the following it works but this will set for the complete script I want to set for just for inferencing
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = 1 # export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1

Comment: why don't you make a separate script just for your inference? Why do you want to benchmark on one core?

Comment: I want to benchmark only on one core because in my production env I have the luxury to use only a single core. I am not sure If forking a separate process will guarantee to run it on the same core.